# Java: Refresh a JTable in a if-loop using PreparedStatement (sql)

Tags: java, postgresql, if-statement, prepared-statement, actionlistener

I'm trying to make a research window that would be able to find an information in a PostgreSql database using Phone number OR name of the person I look for. My problem is that my JTable is in a If-loop ( To check if the user search with the name or the phone number ) so if the user use the window to search two different people, my code will add a new JTable below the first one instead of refreshing it.

Here is the ActionListener that cause my problem.

```
        class OkListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            try {

            String name = nameField.getText();
            String phone = phoneField.getText();
            Connection conn = CCConnection.getInstance();
            if (!phone.isEmpty() && name.isEmpty() ){


                String sqlName = "select * from creditcopie where telephone = ?";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatementName = CCConnection.getInstance().prepareStatement(sqlName, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                preparedStatementName.setString(1, phone);
                ResultSet rs = preparedStatementName.executeQuery();
                JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
                container.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                container.revalidate();
                container.repaint();


            }

            else if (phone.isEmpty() && !name.isEmpty() ){
                String sqlName = "select * from creditcopie where nom = ?";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatementName = CCConnection.getInstance().prepareStatement(sqlName, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                preparedStatementName.setString(1, name);
                ResultSet rs = preparedStatementName.executeQuery();
                JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
                container.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                container.revalidate();
                container.repaint();
                confirmButton.setEnabled(false);

            }

            else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to do the research", "Error! ", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);   
            }



            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
```

And this is the buildTableModel

```
            public DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
                throws SQLException {

            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

            // names of columns
            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
                columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
            }

            // data of the table
            Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
                for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                    vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
                }
                data.add(vector);
            }

            return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        }
```

Comment: Do not create your JTable inside action performed, you need to update the table model instead. Have the JTable instance out of your actionPerformed and just build and set the table model.

Comment: It worked! Thanks.